# Dropdown Toggle Split in Bootstrap Navwalker Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, bootstrap-5

It's about Wordpress Theme Development.

When working on a WordPress theme using Bootstrap 5, I used [Bootstrap NavWalker](https://github.com/wp-bootstrap/wp-bootstrap-navwalker) to create a navigation bar (navbar). The dropdown feature is already built into Bootstrap NavWalker, including the dropdown arrow integrated into the menu.

Now, I want to customize it a bit. I want the text in the menu to take the user to a link when clicked. However, when the user clicks on the dropdown arrow, I want it to reveal the submenu instead.

In summary, I want the user to navigate to a link by clicking on the menu text, and show the submenu when the dropdown arrow is clicked. Is it possible to do that? here is my code:

header.php:

```
<div class="col-12">
  <nav class="main-menu navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">
    <button class="navbar-toggler ms-auto mb-3" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <?php
        wp_nav_menu(array(
          'theme_location'  => 'kreasi_main_menu',
          'depth'           => 4, 
          'container'       => false,
          'menu_class'      => 'navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0',
          'fallback_cb'     => 'WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker::fallback',
          'walker'          => new WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker(),
        ));
      ?>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

this is my script-navbar.js, i'm using node.js:

```
import $ from 'jquery';

class scriptNavbar {
    constructor() {
        this.events();
    }

    events() {
        $(document).ready(() => {
            // Toggle dropdown-menu on click
            $('.main-menu .dropdown > a').on('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                // Close other dropdown-menus within the same level
                $(this).parent().siblings('.dropdown.show').removeClass('show');
                // Toggle class for the clicked dropdown-menu
                $(this).next('.dropdown-menu').toggleClass('show');
            });

            // Close dropdown-menus when clicking outside of them
            $(document).on('click', function (e) {
                if (!$(e.target).closest('.main-menu .dropdown').length) {
                    $('.main-menu .dropdown .dropdown-menu').removeClass('show');
                }
            });

            // Prevent closing the dropdown-menu when clicking inside it
            $('.main-menu .dropdown-menu').on('click', function (e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
            });
        });
    }
}

export default scriptNavbar;
```

And this is my style-navbar.scss:

```
/* Default styles */
.main-menu {
    padding: 0;
}

.main-menu ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 500;
    border-radius: 0;
}

.main-menu ul li {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0 5px 0 0;
}

.main-menu ul li:last-child {
    margin: 0;
}

.main-menu > ul li a,
.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    color: #303030;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 7px 15px 20px;
}

.main-menu ul li a.nav-link:first-child {
    padding-left: 0 !important;
}

.main-menu ul li ul {
    background-color: #000;
}

.main-menu ul li ul li {
    margin: 0;
}

.main-menu ul li ul li a {
    padding: 0.5rem;
    color: #fff;
}

.main-menu .navbar-nav .active > .nav-link {
    color: #CA2424;
}

.main-menu .dropdown-item:focus,
.main-menu .dropdown-item:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #272c33;
}

.main-menu .dropdown-item.active,
.main-menu .dropdown-item:active {
    background-color: #d2335b;
}

.main-menu .navbar-toggler {
    border: none;
    padding-right: 3%;
}

.main-menu .dropdown-toggle::after {
    vertical-align: 0.155em;
}

.main-menu ul li .dropdown-menu .dropdown > a::after {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 0.355em;
    vertical-align: 0.2em;
    content: "";
    border-top: 0.3em solid;
    border-right: 0.3em solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 0;
    border-left: 0.3em solid transparent;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.main-menu .dropdown-menu li {
    display: block;
}

.main-menu .dropdown-menu .dropdown-menu {
    top: -1px;
    left: 100%;
}

.navbar-brand {
    display: contents;
}

/* Responsive styles */
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .main-menu {
        border-top: 2px solid #f2f2f2;
        padding: 2%;
        margin-top: 2%;
    }

    /* Add background color to third-level submenu */
    .main-menu .dropdown-menu ul li {
        margin-left: 8%;
        position: relative;
        padding-left: 8%;
    }

    .main-menu .dropdown-menu ul li::before {
        font-family: "dashicons";
        content: "\f474";
        position: absolute;
        transform: scaleX(-1);
        font-size: larger;
        color: #fff;
        margin: 5px 3%;
        left: -8%;
    }
}
```

If you want to look my theme folder where every my code exist, you can check my github here:

https://github.com/achann08/wc_course/tree/main/wp-content/themes/kreasi

I need help, thank you very much.

To dropdown toggle split in Bootstrap Navwalker.